# wireguard vpn is failing with error: Cannot find device "wg0"

Tags: vpn, wireguard

Hello I am very new to ubuntu, I installed wireguard almost 6 months ago, and it was working fine, untill yesterday when my ubuntu was updated, the wirguard does not want to come up, and gives the below status:

```
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo wg-quick[5463]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo wg-quick[5463]: Error: Unknown device type.
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo wg-quick[5463]: Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo wg-quick[5463]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo wg-quick[5463]: Cannot find device "wg0"
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 31 08:41:03 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

here is my ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 9):

Try reinstalling package `wireguard-dkms` (remove and install again). Probably afterwards a reboot will be needed.

Comment: works, wireguard-dkms + reboot for Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Answer (score 2):

Run the Following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-resolved
```

and reboot the system

It has worked in my case, I hope it will be helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

for me the dkms way proposed by [@Błotosmętek](https://askubuntu.com/users/204560/b%C5%82otosm%C4%99tek) worked in the beginning, but after doing an experimental `systemctl restart ...` it never recovered, with errors such as:

```
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen wg-quick[6005]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen wg-quick[5915]: [#] resolvconf -d tun.wg0 -f
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen wg-quick[5915]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 10 10:46:46 ryzen systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

Thus resorted to the networkmanager way described here: https://www.xmodulo.com/wireguard-vpn-network-manager-gui.html